# crontab executes for root but not for common user

Tags: cron, reboot

Cron isn't executing for my user (here k) at reboot.
I put on a test script to see if it executes as root with:

```
crontab -e
```

then put into crontab:

```
@reboot echo date >>  ~/reboot-dates
```

which is working and creates the fine inside /root/. Now I did the same for user k:

```
crontab -e -u k
```

and added the above test script line both with ~/ and full path:

```
@reboot echo date >>  /home/k/reboot-dates
@reboot echo date >>  ~/reboot-dates
```

I also put k in /etc/cron.allow:

```
echo k >> /etc/cron.allow
```

but it isn't starting as user k. I see the cron task is running both as root and user k, when i do:

```
ps -ef|grep cron|grep -v grep
```

I tried to edit the users crontab both as root and as user k but it isn't working.
I tried as root with runuser -l k -c "command" which does not work, I also tried with sleep 10 && "runuser..." still no success... these commands are working outside of cron.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is what works in crontab root file:

```
@reboot /sbin/runuser -l k -c "date >> ~/reboot-dates"
```

If anyone got a better solution please notice me. Sadly only root can add cronjobs this way. You also might cat /var/mail/root to see syntax errors such as "runuser command not found" etc.

Also the output is not directed to the user but instead is printed into roots mail. So this solution is really bad.